# ACL grants access to all Users in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I try to understand how ACL works but even if I set them for an item (`$client` in this case), everybody has access.

**SET ACL**

```
public function setACL($repository, $mask, $selectUser = false)
{

    $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($repository);
    $acl = $this->aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

    if($selectUser === false){
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }else{
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($selectUser);
    }

    $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

    $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, $mask);
    $this->aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);

    return;

}
```

`$selectUser` is for setting it manually (via Console Comannd etc.) does it work that way at all?

**GET ACL**

```
public function getACL($repository, $granted)
{

    if (is_array($repository)) {
        foreach ($repository as $rp) {
            if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($granted, get_class($rp))) {

                $this->get('log')->writeLog('Access denied.', __LINE__, 3);
                return new JsonResponse(array(
                    'result' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Not allowed'
                ));
            }
        }
    } else {

        if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($granted, get_class($repository))) {

            $this->get('log')->writeLog('Access denied.', __LINE__, 3);
            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'result' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Not allowed'
            ));
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Set ACL for `$client`**

```
$this->get('global_functions')->setACL($client, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
```

But when I try to

**Get ACL**

```
$this->get('global_functions')->getACL($client, 'VIEW');
```

I get access with whatever user I am trying this...

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it myself...

`$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($granted, get_class($repository))` should be `$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($granted, $repository)`